# Is it possible to get query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and need help I have 4 tables:

```
helmet                                  arm
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+
|  id  |   name  | def | weight |       |  id  |   name  | def | weight |
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+
|   1  |  head1  |  5  |   2.2  |       |   1  |   arm1  |  4  |   2.7  |
|   2  |  head2  |  6  |   2.9  |       |   2  |   arm2  |  5  |   3.1  |
|   3  |  head3  |  7  |   3.5  |       |   3  |   arm3  |  2  |   1.8  |
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+

body                                    leg
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+
|  id  |   name  | def | weight |       |  id  |   name  | def | weight |
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+
|   1  |  body1  |  10  |  5.5  |       |   1  |   leg1  |  8  |   3.5  |
|   2  |  body2  |  5   |  2.4  |       |   2  |   leg2  |  5  |   2.0  |
|   3  |  body3  |  17  |  6.9  |       |   3  |   leg3  |  8  |   1.8  |
+------+---------+-----+--------+       +------+---------+-----+--------+`
```

I'm looking for the highest totaldef which totalweight <= input
like this: totalweight <= 10

Query:

```
select 
    helmet.name as hname, body.name as bname, 
    arm.name as aname, leg.name as lname,
    helmet.poise + body.poise + arm.poise + leg.poise as totalpoise, 
    helmet.weight + body.weight + arm.weight + leg.weight as totalweight 
from 
    helmet 
inner join 
    body on 1=1
inner join 
    arm on 1=1
inner join 
    leg on 1=1 
where 
    helmet.weight + body.weight + arm.weight + leg.weight <= 10
order by 
    totalpoise desc 
limit 5
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
| hname | bname | aname | lname | totaldef | totalweight |
+-------+-------+------ +-------+----------+-------------+
| head2 | body2 |  arm1 |  leg3 |    23    |     9.8     |
| head1 | body2 |  arm2 |  leg3 |    23    |     9.5     |
| head3 | body2 |  arm3 |  leg3 |    22    |     9.5     |
| head1 | body2 |  arm1 |  leg3 |    22    |     9.1     |
| head2 | body2 |  arm3 |  leg3 |    21    |     8.9     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

The problem is each table has about 100 rows so the possible results are 100m+ rows. It's take a long time for query. I'm not sure it's about my hardware or types of database or query.

P.S: I use HDD and have 8GB of ram. I had tested on MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Update
I didn't create Index yet.

Is this explain plan?
[explain plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrZXO.jpg)

How long does it take?
It depends on input.
On MySQL it's about few minutes - couple of hours.
On PostgreSQL it's take about 30 seconds - 2 minutes.

Update 2  My tables never change. So can I store all result in a table? Does it help?

Update 3 I think about partitioning. It's may be much faster but the problem is if some [armor set] in lower partition has totaldef more than [armor set] in upper partition.
example:

```
[head1,arm1,body1,leg1][totaldef 25][totalweight 9.9]
[head2,arm2,body2,leg2][totaldef 20][totalweight 11.0]
```

So partition totalweight >10 gonna miss that [armor set] because it's in other partition.

This is CSV file for anyone who want to test.  [CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1sb9ad0qqslfz6/csv.rar?dl=0)

Update 4 I think the fastest way is create [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) but I guess the key to performance is sort it. I don't know which sort can help materialized view or Index but I sorted them both and it's helpful.

I didn't expect to get a lot of help like this. Thank you.

Comment: You missed the most important info: indexes???

Comment: ... And explain plan

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: And if it was me, I'd probably have one table instead of four

Comment: @Strawberry if you do that. What will your query be to find the four names ?

Comment: How long is a long time?

Comment: Does that tables changes frequently? If not then you can to create materialized view on its cartesian join with appropriate indexes. And use it instead.

Comment: Its a bin packing problem http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/tags/Bin+Packing/default.aspx may be useful

Comment: @devoh the comments section isn't the appropriate forum for such questions

Comment: If performance is most important for you, then store results in new table which will contain struct like `helm_id,body_id,arm_id,leg_id,weight_sum,def_sum`

Comment: @Strawberry you should add your answer. Then we could discuss about it and maybe slowbs and the community.will find it helpful

Comment: Re update 2 - it depends. The creation of a 100m record table will take a while but if your intention is to iterate "helmet.weight + body.weight + arm.weight + leg.weight" with different value conditions (10,20,15...) then it's probably worth doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with the appropriate index performs reasonably well, 1.8 sec in my aging SSD desktop with the stock Postgresql config:

```
create materialized view v as
select
    h.name as hname, b.name as bname, a.name as aname, l.name as lname,
    total_poise, total_weight
from
    helmet h
    cross join
    body b
    cross join
    arm a
    cross join
    leg l
    cross join lateral (
        select
            h.weight + b.weight + l.weight + a.weight as total_weight,
            h.poise + b.poise + l.poise + a.poise as total_poise
    ) total
order by total_poise desc, total_weight
;

create index v_index on v (total_poise desc, total_weight);
```

Execution and analyze:

```
select *
from v
where total_weight <= 10
order by total_poise desc, total_weight
limit 5
;
         hname         |          bname           |         aname          |          lname           | total_poise | total_weight 
-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+-------------+--------------
 Fume Sorcerer Mask+10 | Moon Butterfly Wings+5   | Velstadt`s Gauntlets+5 | Prisoner`s Waistcloth+10 |          20 |          9.4
 Fume Sorcerer Mask+10 | Lion Warrior Cape+10     | Velstadt`s Gauntlets+5 | Prisoner`s Waistcloth+10 |          20 |          9.5
 Fume Sorcerer Mask+10 | Red Lion Warrior Cape+10 | Velstadt`s Gauntlets+5 | Prisoner`s Waistcloth+10 |          20 |          9.5
 Fume Sorcerer Mask+10 | Moon Butterfly Wings+5   | Velstadt`s Gauntlets+5 | Lion Warrior Skirt+10    |          20 |          9.6
 Fume Sorcerer Mask+10 | Moon Butterfly Wings+5   | Velstadt`s Gauntlets+5 | Moon Butterfly Skirt+10  |          20 |          9.6


explain analyze
select *
from v
where total_weight <= 10
order by total_poise desc, total_weight
limit 5
;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..11.71 rows=5 width=88) (actual time=1847.680..1847.694 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using v_index on v  (cost=0.57..11191615.70 rows=5020071 width=88) (actual time=1847.678..1847.691 rows=5 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (total_weight <= '10'::double precision)
 Planning time: 0.126 ms
 Execution time: 1847.722 ms
```

Comment: you forgot the main condition 'totalweight <= 10'

Comment: @devoh All conditions are covered in this line: `where 10 >= all (array[total_weight, h.weight, b.weight, l.weight, a.weight])`

Comment: You 're right. My bad. I will add your query to my benchmark. 204.438 second

Comment: This seems the fastest I ever try. It's still slow when input in range 0 - 10 but just only 15 - 20 seconds and it's make my HDD 100% usage. So I think it's can faster if I change to SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. I don't know any special method for your situation. If I were you I will test the following : Body seems heavier than helmet, arm and leg. So I will query first on that table and then on each join and make sure the sum of the weight doesn't exceed your input. as follow :

```
SELECT helmet.name AS hname, body.name AS bname, arm.name AS aname, leg.name AS lname,
helmet.poise + body.poise + arm.poise + leg.poise AS totalpoise, 
helmet.weight + body.weight + arm.weight + leg.weight AS totalweight 
FROM body 
    INNER JOIN helmet 
    ON 1=1 
        AND body.weight + helmet.weight <= 10
    INNER JOIN arm 
    ON 1=1 
        AND body.weight + helmet.weight + arm.weight <= 10
    INNER JOIN leg 
    ON 1=1 
        AND body.weight + helmet.weight + arm.weight + leg.weight <= 10
WHERE body.weight <= 10
ORDER BY totalpoise DESC limit 5
```

Also as @juergen-d mention in a comment, indexes would have an impact on the performance. You could benchmark the difference with or without indexes on each weight columns.

For PostgreSQL :

```
CREATE INDEX index_body_on_weight ON body(weight);
```

After some discussion with zerkms and Laurenz Albe they agree to say **those three indexes are useless and should not be used** : (If I have time I 'll do a benchmark)

```
CREATE INDEX index_helmet_on_weight ON helmet(weight);
CREATE INDEX index_arm_on_weight ON arm(weight);
CREATE INDEX index_leg_on_weight ON leg(weight);
```

Benchmark on PostgreQSL 9.3.5 :

```
 slowbs's Query : 107.628 second
 my proposition Query : 12.066 second
 my proposition Query : 16.257 second (with only index_body_on_weight)
 my proposition Query : 13.217 second (with 4 indexes)
```

**Benchmark's Conclusion :** indexes in that case are inefficient. @zerkms and @Laurenz Albe were right.

**Last but not least, please share your results.**

Comment: "indexes would have an impact on the performance" --- what indexes would you suggest? "on each weight columns" --- could you please share your thoughts on why it would be helpful and how exactly postgresql might have used those indexes?

Comment: @zerkms  "indexes on each weight columns.". I didn't write the syntax cause slowbs is using at least 2 RDBMS.

Comment: Why do you think having separate indexes on every column would be any helpful?

Comment: @zerkms Cause it's how RDBMS functions :-) Joking. As you suggest I will improve my answer.

Comment: Aside from jokes: having redundant (see useless) indexes would make harm, not good.

Comment: @zerkms In general you need an index for a WHERE (or ON in case of join) condition. Since 1=1 isn't a real one (but just a way to say I want to combine all rows in those tables) the only one way to improve the performance of this query is by adding indexes on weight columns. Explication: Except for the 'SELECT' at the end of the query you only need two columns to perform the query (id, weight) on each table. Adding an index on each weight column just materialize that. I don't know if my explanation is clear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136018/discussion-between-devoh-and-zerkms).

Comment: I think that the answer is good, but all except the first index are useless and should be removed. A superfluous index is harmful because it wastes space and hurts DML performance.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's for these reason I wrote 'You could benchmark the difference with or without indexes on each weight columns.' I am willing to learn from that experience too

Comment: Well, you need to put a bold statement there, that it's just your guess and you not sure if it will be any helpful (it will not), so that other people did not learn from it.

Comment: @devoh no index can help with an expression like `col1 + col2 < n`. If you rephrase that to `col2 < n - col1`, the index could be used if the databases chooses a nested loop join. Maybe you should update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the explanation. I edited my answer and I will try to do a test -- stubborn until I fail

Comment: @devoh I created index on body(weight) and use your query. It's faster if input < 20 but if > 20 it's still slow as my query.

Comment: I am doing a benchmark. Any index seems useless. Don't use them. I will edit my answer.

Comment: If your input could be < 20 or > 20 and if you need fast response time, you will need to store all combinations in a table and manage the addition or deletions of elements (head, body, arm, leg). Materialized views (as mentioned Abelisto) will be easier to manage if your tables are going to change frequently.

Comment: @devoh I used to think about it but I can't do because there is possibility to some result has totalweight< 20 but totaldef > some result has totalweight >20.
About < 20 or > 20 I mean your query is faster than mine when low value input but when high value like 20 or above it's slow as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Because your table never change then you can cache the intermediate data. For PostgreSQL it could be [`materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html):

```
create materialized view equipments as
  select
    h.id as helmet_id, a.id as arm_id, b.id as body_id, l.id as leg_id,
    (h.def+a.def+b.def+l.def) as total_def,
    (h.weight+a.weight+b.weight+l.weight) as total_weight
  from helmet as h, arm as a, body as b, leg as l;
create index i_def on equipments(total_def);
create index i_weight on equipments(total_weight);
```

It is one-time heavy operation, but after that queries like:

```
select *
from equipments
where total_weight <= 10
order by total_def desc
limit 5;
```

will be much faster. And of course you can to join your tables to the query above to get details about equipments.

And you can to call [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) if tables was changed.

I am not familiar with MySQL, but you can to google for `mysql materialized view` or just to use a regular table.

---

**Yet another attempt: [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).**

(`drop materialized view equipments` if it was created in the previous attempt)

```
create table equipments(
  helmet_id int, arm_id int, body_id int, leg_id int,
  total_weight float, total_def float);
```

There is the basic table. Next we will create partitions. For example, if there is max total weight is 40 then there are four partitions for 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 and 30-40 total weight:

```
create table equipments_10 (check (total_weight>0 and total_weight<=10))
  inherits (equipment); 
create table equipments_20 (check (total_weight>10 and total_weight<=20))
  inherits (equipment); 
create table equipments_30 (check (total_weight>20 and total_weight<=30))
  inherits (equipment); 
create table equipments_40 (check (total_weight>30))
  inherits (equipment);
```

Fill our tables:

```
insert into equipments
  select
    h.id as helmet_id, a.id as arm_id, b.id as body_id, l.id as leg_id,
    (h.def+a.def+b.def+l.def) as total_def,
    (h.weight+a.weight+b.weight+l.weight) as total_weight
  from helmet as h, arm as a, body as b, leg as l;
```

And create a lot of indexes to give PostgreSQL chance to select the most efficient execution plan:

```
create index i_equip_total_def on equipments(total_def);
create index i_equip_total_weight on equipments(total_weight); 
create index i_equip_10_total_def on equipments_10(total_def);
create index i_equip_10_total_weight on equipments_10(total_weight); 
create index i_equip_20_total_def on equipments_20(total_def);
create index i_equip_20_total_weight on equipments_20(total_weight); 
create index i_equip_30_total_def on equipments_30(total_def);
create index i_equip_30_total_weight on equipments_30(total_weight); 
create index i_equip_40_total_def on equipments_40(total_def);
create index i_equip_40_total_weight on equipments_40(total_weight);
```

Finally compute statistics about the data:

```
analyze equipments;
analyze equipments_10;
analyze equipments_20;
analyze equipments_30;
analyze equipments_40;
```

The query is similar as in the previous attempt.

PS: [Here is my test](http://pastebin.com/5T4Q7iJY) if somebody want to try it.
PPS: On my tests each of queries, independent on parameter is less the 0.5 ms (on the my prehistoric HW).

Comment: I try this and it's much faster when I order by total_def asc. But for desc it's only fast when high value input such as 30 or above but if input less than 30 it's very slow.

Comment: @slowbs Yes, I see the problem. Added yet another solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun & completeness: a recursive solution on a unified table. This may be not the fastest, but it might win if the tables get larger and an index can be used. (trivial examples like the `3*3*3*3` will often yield hash-join plans, or even nested table scans)

---

```
-- the data
CREATE TABLE helmet(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name text, poise INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight DECIMAL (4,2) );
INSERT INTO helmet(id, name, poise, weight) VALUES
(   1, 'head1', 5, 2.2) ,(   2, 'head2', 6, 2.9) ,(   3, 'head3', 7, 3.5) ;

CREATE TABLE body (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name text, poise INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight DECIMAL (4,2) );
INSERT INTO body(id, name, poise, weight) VALUES
 (   1, 'body1', 10, 5.5) ,(   2, 'body2', 5 , 2.4) ,(   3, 'body3', 17, 6.9) ;

CREATE TABLE arm (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name text, poise INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight DECIMAL (4,2) );
INSERT INTO arm(id, name, poise, weight) VALUES
 (   1, 'arm1', 4, 2.7) ,(   2, 'arm2', 5, 3.1) ,(   3, 'arm3', 2, 1.8) ;

CREATE TABLE leg (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name text, poise INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, weight DECIMAL (4,2) );
INSERT INTO leg(id, name, poise, weight) VALUES
 (   1, 'leg1', 8, 3.5) ,(   2, 'leg2', 5, 2.0) ,(   3, 'leg3', 8, 1.8) ;


-- combine the four tables into one
CREATE table allgear AS
SELECT 1 AS gid, 'helmet' AS gear, h.id, h.name, h.poise, h.weight FROM helmet h
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS gid, 'body' AS gear, b.id, b.name, b.poise, b.weight FROM body b
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS gid, 'arm' AS gear, a.id, a.name, a.poise, a.weight FROM arm a
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS gid, 'leg' AS gear, l.id, l.name, l.poise, l.weight FROM leg l
        ;

-- add som structure ...
ALTER TABLE allgear ADD PRIMARY KEY(gid, id);
CREATE INDEX ON allgear(gid, weight);
VACUUM ANALYZE allgear;

-- SELECT * FROM allgear ORDER by gid, id;


-- Recursive query with some pruning on the partial results.
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH recursive rrr AS (
        SELECT gid AS gid
                , ARRAY[ name] AS arr
                , poise AS totpoise
                , weight AS totweight
        FROM allgear
        WHERE gid = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ag.gid
                , rrr.arr || ARRAY[ag.name] AS arr
                , rrr.totpoise +ag.poise AS totpoise
                , (rrr.totweight +ag.weight)::decimal(4,2) AS totweight
        FROM allgear ag
        JOIN rrr ON ag.gid = rrr.gid +1 AND (rrr.totweight + ag.weight)::DECIMAL(4,2) <= 10.0::DECIMAL(4,2)
        )
SELECT * FROM rrr
WHERE gid = 4 -- the gid of the final one
ORDER BY totweight DESC
LIMIT 5
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
 gid |           arr           | totpoise | totweight 
-----+-------------------------+----------+-----------
   4 | {head2,body2,arm1,leg2} |       20 |     10.00
   4 | {head1,body2,arm3,leg1} |       20 |      9.90
   4 | {head2,body2,arm1,leg3} |       23 |      9.80
   4 | {head3,body2,arm3,leg2} |       19 |      9.70
   4 | {head1,body2,arm2,leg2} |       20 |      9.70
(5 rows)
```

---

Note: I get a few more combinations, probably because I used `DECIMAL(4,2)` instead of a floating point type.

---

Extra: we can add some extra pruning (even in the lower levels) if we know what the minimum weight is that the remaining levels (gear-types) will add. I added an extra table for this.

---

```
CREATE TABLE minima AS
SELECT gid, MIN(weight) AS mimi
FROM allgear
GROUP BY gid;
-- add an extra level ...
INSERT INTO minima(gid, mimi) VALUES (5, 0.0);

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH recursive rrr AS (
        SELECT gid AS gid
                , ARRAY[ name] AS arr
                , poise AS totpoise
                , weight AS totweight
        FROM allgear
        WHERE gid = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ag.gid
                , rrr.arr || ARRAY[ag.name] AS arr
                , rrr.totpoise +ag.poise AS totpoise
                , (rrr.totweight +ag.weight)::decimal(4,2) AS totweight
        FROM allgear ag
        JOIN rrr ON ag.gid = rrr.gid+1
        -- Do some extra pruning: Partial sum + the missing parts should not sum up to more than 10
        JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT SUM(mimi) AS debt
                FROM minima
                WHERE gid > ag.gid
                ) susu ON (susu.debt +rrr.totweight + ag.weight)::DECIMAL(4,2) <= 10.0::DECIMAL(4,2)

        )
SELECT * FROM rrr
WHERE gid = 4
ORDER BY totweight DESC
LIMIT 5
        ;
```

Comment: I try this it's make my HDD run 100%. It's faster when input in range 0 - 10 but otherwise it's still slow. I think if I change to SSD it's might faster.I didn't try about Extra yet.

Comment: The recursive method depends on (early) pruning. If the upper levels cannot prune anything, it will still need to explore almost the entire N*N*N*N tree.